# Trying to make an icon work while modifying a django template

Tags: html, django, django-templates, font-awesome, web-frontend

How can make this icon show in my modified django template:

I tried using font awesome link but it did not work

the template was downloaded online and i am currently modfying it hence me encountering this issue. i triend downloading other fonts online but then none is the same as this

Comment: Where is the template?